# Worklight application's page fail to load after splashscreen

Tags: android, splash-screen, ibm-mobilefirst

I've got an issue displaying my Worklight homepage after splash-screen display.
(for information, my app was working well before).

After adding many spashscreen.png files in res/drawable(s) folders, i've updated the java code in my .java homepage class:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splashscreen);
super.loadUrl(getWebMainFilePath(), 5000);
```

Then i added the following in my .html homepage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
// hide splash-screen
    navigator.spashscreen.hide();
    }
</script>
```

The splash-screen is well displayed, and after 5 seconds, the screen goes black.

Here is the error logs from my htc device:

```
03-08 16:08:08.354: E/libEGL(2722): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
03-08 16:08:08.354: E/SurfaceTexture(1446): [SurfaceView] abandon: surfaceTexture(0x0x9df580) has been abandoned!
03-08 16:08:08.724: E/SurfaceTexture(1446): [Starting com.Maquette] abandon: SurfaceTexture(0x0xa1ca18) has been abandoned!
03-08 16:08:08.744: E/SurfaceTexture(1446): [com.htc.launcher/com.htc.launcher.Launcher] abandon: SurfaceTexture(0x0xa5ce18) has been abandoned!
03-08 16:08:13.068: E/SurfaceTexture(1446): [com.Maquette/com.Maquette.Maquette] abandon: SurfaceTexture(0x0x9df580) has been abandoned!
```

Thanx for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try the answers given in this thread by @user2124658: [Worklight App Splash Screen on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496704/worklight-app-splash-screen-on-android)

If you are on Worklight 5.0.5.x try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl(getWebMainFilePath());  // yes, this is an extra invocation
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.loadUrl(getWebMainFilePath(), 5000);
}
```

If you are on Worklight 5.0.6.x try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.bindBrowser(appView);
    super.loadUrl(getWebMainFilePath(), 5000);
}
```

Comment: I was just got stuck in the same issue, thanks Idan it works for me.