# IBM Worklight 6.1- How to reduce splash screen duration around 1 second for android?

Tags: android, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using IBM Worklight 6.1 for my mobile app project. My question is how to reduce splash screen duration around 1 second. I and my colleague already try many solutions from stackoverflow regarding to this issue.

[IBM Worklight 5.0.6 - How to add a splash screen to Android environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028944/ibm-worklight-5-0-6-how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-android-environment) - stay on splash screen

[phonegap - splash screen for Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156841/phonegap-splash-screen-for-android-app) - not working

[Worklight App Splash Screen on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496704/worklight-app-splash-screen-on-android) - blank screen

Until now the splash screen takes a lot around 10 seconds. We test it on Samsung Note 2 and compile it using eclipse Juno.

This is our source code for splash screen.

```
package com.WorklightMobile;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.worklight.androidgap.WLDroidGap;

public class WorklightMobile extends WLDroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    }

    /**
     * onWLInitCompleted is called when the Worklight runtime framework initialization is complete
     */
    @Override
    public void onWLInitCompleted(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.loadUrl(getWebMainFilePath(), 1000);
        // Add custom initialization code after this line
    }

}
```

Check this out my repo - https://github.com/datomnurdin/worklight-mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot.
The current mechanism in Worklight 6.1.0 is remove the splash image on `EnvInit`.

What you can try to do is to remove the splash image Worklight uses (`native\res\drawable\splash.9.png`) and implement your own splash mechanism.

Comment: Once the environment finishes to initializes; It is an internal process of the Worklight framework.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you remove the splash screen and you have heavy loading then you will see a white screen... Just let the splash stay displayed until the app is displayed.